# How can I handle CSS styles in JSP correctly while displaying to fix alignment?

Tags: css, jsp

While [testing](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication) `JSP` files, I'm getting the problem with displaying on the screen because of alignment:

[image]

I want the text to be center aligned and not have a configuration heading on top.

Here's my example of `JSP` file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <%@include file="/includes/head.jsp"%>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgba(26, 35, 115, 0.47);
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="text-center vsc-initialized">
<%@include file="/includes/header.jsp"%>
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Welcome</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">to</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Project Management</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">System</h1>
    </main></div>
<%@include file="/includes/footer.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me, please, is it `CSS` problem or `JSP`? Do I need to fix something in `JSP` to get another result of displaying?

If you need some *additional information*, I'm ready to update this question.

I appreciate any recommendations/ideas here.

Comment: You just want the text to be center right? I think adding class `text-center` beside `flex-column` will do the task, assuming you using bootstrap css.

Comment: Thank you for the provided idea - yes, I want to the text to be center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not specifically with `css`, but in the way of displaying.

After I changed the `path` and the way of displaying inside `application.properties`:

instead of:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/jsp/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

to:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and `location` of `JSP` files:

instead of the folder:

```
/resources/templates/jsp/
```

to the folder:

```
/webapp/
```

the problem with *alignment* while using `CSS` styles in `JSP`, was fixed.